# Grub rescue mode

Tags: boot

So I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and deleted Windows 10 from my laptop. I then installed linux mint mate, because I wanted to use it for gaming only, but it turned out, that ubuntu served me well. So I deleted the partition for Mint and allocated the free space to Ubuntu. After i rebooted, I get a screen which says grub rescue. I followed some tutorials online, but none of them seem to work for me. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same issue earlier (few months back). I remember that changing the the bios from UEFI to legacy or viceversa. I don't remember exactly. give a try once.

Comment: If it doesn't solve, try running [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? If not, you can try [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246223/what-will-happen-if-we-put-the-ubuntu-installed-disk-from-lenovo-into-dell/1246234#1246234). Looks to me the problem is very similar, because your grub installation is pointing to a partition that does not exist anymore (Linux Mint). From rescue mode you can tell grub where grub.cfg and the grub modules from the Ubuntu installation are located.

Answer (score 0):

boot from your Ubuntu live CD/ USB and follow instructions given in link of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) page. Follow the second option:

**install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

And follow **Recommended repair** for more detail.

You can also refer to website of [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)

If it does not help. Tell here